# Need help as a beginner with function def

Tags: python

I am new trying to learn to program. I downloaded Python 3.9.5 and trying a function as follows:

```
>>> def f(x):
    return x**3
f(3)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong or do I need to download something more?

Comment: `Try running this in a separate Python file. It works there. Also, f(3) only returns 27 and does not print out anything. You may want to put print(f(3))`

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue exactly, but I can get close. Are you using IDLE? BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: The issue her was the indentation as there was no indent on line two you are getting error, python interpreter expects indent so check indent and run again

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a a newline:

```
def f(x): return x**3 
f(3)
```

Then it is correct syntax.

Comment: Neither of these work in the REPL. The first one doesn't return anything (though I don't know why) and the second one raises a SyntaxError.

Comment: I figured it out: in the first one, `f(3)` is **inside** the function, not outside of it. However it's never called because the function returns first.

Comment: @wjandrea you were right about the first one, but the second doesn't give me any errors.

Comment: Huh, weird. Are you copy-pasting the whole thing, or one line at a time with another newline between them? And are you using the regular Python REPL or something else like IDLE or IPython?

Comment: @wjandrea I'm not using the REPL, just a online python [interpreter](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/).

Comment: Oh, I see, you're using the "main.py" section. If you copy-paste the whole thing into the "Shell" section, you get the syntax error.

Comment: @wjandrea gotcha

Answer (score 2):

Once you hit the <kbd>enter</kbd> after `def f(x):`, add 4 <kbd>space</kbd> indentation.
And then hit <kbd>enter</kbd> twice until you see another `>>>` prompt.

```
>>> def f(x):
...     return x**3
... 
>>> f(3)
27
```